# 'Use of Unresolved Identifier' in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I have been making an app, and everything has been working great. But today I made a new class like usual and for some reason in this class I can't access Public/Global variable from other classes. All the other classes can, but now when ever I try to make a new class I can't. How would this be fixed?

I am using Swift and Xcode 6.

Working Class:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Parse
import CoreData

var signedIn = true

class ViewController: UIViewController {
```

New Class:

```
import UIKit

class NewClass: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        signedIn = false

}
```

But on `signedIn = false`

I get the error:

> use of unresolved identifier "signedIn"

Comment: and yes I have deleted and recreated this class several times

Comment: Please show your code, both working and not working.

Comment: Can you specify the version of XCode / Swift you're using (if it's beta or not) ?

Comment: @Ichamp Xcode 6.1 not beta.

Comment: Is this your complete code? because of your indentation it looks like you are missing a curly bracket `}` at the end of your `viewDidLoad()`

Answer (score 298, accepted):

One possible issue is that your new class has a different Target or different Targets from the other one.

For example, it might have a testing target while the other one doesn't. For this specific case, you have to include all of your classes in the testing target or none of them.

[image: Targets]

Comment: If the class is in a different target, make sure you import it on top of your swift file

Comment: hehe, that was a problem. I forgot to setup a target for class. 
Tnx :)

Comment: Oh man, I spent a couple of hours to solve this one. Such a stupid error message. Even Syntax Error is better!

Comment: yup.. it wasn't set in a target for a test project!! thank you

Comment: Mine was in, but I just unchecked then re-checked, which fixed this AND my autocomplete/intellisense came back!

Answer (score 12):

Once I had this problem after renaming a file. I renamed the file from within Xcode, but afterwards Xcode couldn't find the function in the file. Even a clean rebuild didn't fix the problem, but closing and then re-opening the project got the build to work.

Comment: exactly right i removed the files references and then added them again. and everything worked

Answer (score 7):

'Use of Unresolved Identifier' in Swift my also happen when you forgot to import a library. For example I have the error:
[image]

In which I forgot the `UIKit`

> import UIKit

Comment: import AVFoundation

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the compiler gets confused about the syntax in your class. This happens a lot if you paste in source from somewhere else.

Try reducing the "unresolved" source file down to the bare minimum, cleaning and building. Once it builds successfully add all the complexity back to your class.

This has made it go away for me when re-starting Xcode did not work.

Answer (score 4):

Another place I've seen this error is when your project has ***multiple targets*** AND ***multiple bridging headers***. If it's a shared class, make sure you add the resource to all bridging headers.

A good tip to is to look in the left Issue Navigator panel; the root object will show the target that is issuing the complaint.

Answer (score 3):

For me this error happened because I was trying to call a *nested* function. Only thing I had to do to have it fixed was to bring the function *out* to a scope where it was visible.

Comment: By "bring the function out to a scope where it was visible", do you mean mark it as public?

Comment: No. Just purely moving/dragging the function to a different scope ie under the scope of the class

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had an Object-C file which was also in the same Target Membership. I fixed by adding `#import "YourObjectCFileHeader.h"` inside file `Bridging-Header.h`

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't declared it. If you want to use a variable of another class you must use

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var DestViewController : ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController
    DestViewController.signedIn = false
}
```

You have to put this code at the end of the NewClass code

Comment: yes but I have used other classes and they have worked fine without that, it's just when I make this new class.

Comment: This won't work, he has the signedIn variable declared in the global scope, not inside his class.

Answer (score 1):

Your `NewClass` inherits from `UIViewController`. You declared `signedIn` in `ViewController`. If you want `NewClass` to be able to identify that variable it will have to be declared in a class that your `NewClass` inherits from.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error for Mantle Framework in my Objective-Swift Project.
What i tried is ,

1. Check if import  is there in Bridging-Header.h file
2. Change the Target Membership for Framework in **Mantle.h** file as shown in below screenshot.

Toggle between Private Membership first build the project , end up with errors. 
Then build the project with Public Membership  for all the frameworks appeared for **Mantle.h** file, you must get success.

It is just a bug of building with multiple framework in Objective-C Swift project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this is regarding a class you created, be sure that the class is not nested.

F.e

**A.swift**

```
class A {

   class ARelated {

   }
}
```

calling `var b = ARelated()` will give 'Use of unresolved identifier: ARelated'.

You can either:

1) separate the classes if wanted on the same file:

**A.swift**

```
class A {

}

class ARelated {

}
```

2) Maintain your same structure and use the enclosing class to get to the subclass:

`var b = A.ARelated`

Answer (score 0):

I did a stupid mistake. I forgot to mention the class as public or open while updating code in cocoapod workspace.

Please do check whether accesor if working in separate workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare the variable. Just put `var` in front of `signedIn = false`

Comment: I would assume that that is just a typo in the posted code (along with the missing closing bracket on `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was calling my program with the same name as one of its cocoapods. It caused a conflict. Solution: Create a program different name.

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly to your code sample, but in general about the error. I'm writing it here, because Google directs this error to this question, so it may be useful for the other devs.

---

Another use case when you can receive such error is when you're adding a selector to method in another class, eg:

```
private class MockTextFieldTarget {
private(set) var didCallDoneAction = false
    @objc func doneActionHandler() {
        didCallDoneAction = true
    }
}
```

And then in another class:

```
final class UITextFieldTests: XCTestCase {
    func testDummyCode() {
        let mockTarget = MockTextFieldTarget()
        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: mockTarget, action: MockTextFieldTarget.doneActionHandler)
        // ... do something ...
    }
}
```

---

If in the last line you'd simply call `#selector(cancelActionHandler)` instead of `#selector(MockTextFieldTarget.cancelActionHandler)`, you'd get

> use of unresolved identifier

error.