# Use of unresolved identifier FBSDKAppEventNamePurchased

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to log some events in my iOS application using the Facebook Analytics SDK.

First, I logged an event and this works well:

`FBSDKAppEvents.logEvent(FBSDKAppEventNameInitiatedCheckout, valueToSum: price, parameters: parameters)`

Then I tried to log the next one:

`FBSDKAppEvents.logEvent(FBSDKAppEventNamePurchased, valueToSum: price, parameters: parameters)`

And Xcode says that there is no such identifier named `FBSDKAppEventNamePurchased`.

I dived into the Facebook documentation and recognized that it **exists**:

[image]

So, I really have not idea what hell is going on. Does anybody had the same issue?

Comment: see this once it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996730/use-of-unresolved-identifier-in-swift

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, finally I found the reason of the problem and it's solution.

The `FBSDKAppEventNamePurchased` event constant is a private constant of Facebook SDK, so we can't use it in our code directly.

We should use:

`FBSDKAppEvents.logPurchase(price, currency: currencyCode, parameters: parameters)`

instead of:

`FBSDKAppEvents.logEvent(FBSDKAppEventNamePurchased, valueToSum: price, parameters: parameters)`.

I really don't know why Facebook still have the `FBSDKAppEventNamePurchased` event on their documentation pages, but this way is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, we've updated the documentation. Feel free to use the 'Give feedback' button on the documentation page (bottom left) or report the error via developers.facebook.com/bugs too when you see things like this

Comment: @AlexKrzyżanowski Remember to contact a mod to try to get your bounty back. If not, it will be lost.