# Use of unresolved identifier 'GMSPlacesClient' in xcode 7.3.1

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar,
    textDidChange searchText: String){

        let placesClient = GMSPlacesClient()
        placesClient.autocompleteQuery(searchText, bounds: nil, filter: nil) { (results, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            self.resultsArray.removeAll()
            if results == nil {
                return
            }
            for result in results!{
                if let result = result as? GMSAutocompletePrediction{
                    self.resultsArray.append(result.attributedFullText.string)
                }
            }
            self.searchResultController.reloadDataWithArray(self.resultsArray)
        }
}
```

I used this method to searching address in google map. But  `Use of unresolved identifier 'GMSPlacesClient'` error found. How could I resolve this?

Comment: Did you import google map in this view controller?

Comment: import GoogleMaps  Yes i import this.

Comment: Basically it is working fine before install Almofire through cocoapds. But when i add almofire in pods then i update the pod this error occor.

Comment: remove use_framework! then install pod again

Comment: I install pod again but same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Use of unresolved identifier 'GMSPlacesClient'`** error probably occurs when your new class has a different Target(s) from the other one. It is stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996730/use-of-unresolved-identifier-in-swift) that it might have a testing target and the other doesn't. For this case, you have to include all of your classes in the testing target or none of them.

This [blog](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/07/22/swift-access-control-implications-for-unit-testing/) also gives possible solution for error, “Use of unresolved identifier”. Change the access control on your class to public.  Additionally, mark any methods you intend to test with public also. Try also to add the class(es) you want to be able to write unit tests for to the tests target.

You can also check this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793238/googlemaps-sdk-classes-undeclared-type-or-unresolved-identifier). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 14):

If use cocoapod, you need add pod 'GooglePlaces'.
And import GooglePlaces.