# Error use unresolved identifier GMSPlacePickerConfig & GooglePlacePicker? (Google Places 2.0)

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-places

Error use unresolved identifier GMSPlacePickerConfig & GooglePlacePicker? (Google Places 2.0)

```
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces
```

are already declared on top.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roESZ.png)

Answer (score 4):

Now, google has broken it into multiple frameworks. You need to add a new pod 'GooglePlacePicker'.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any error on your code based on this [sample code](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start#add-a-place-picker). If you are using `cocoapod`, you need to add pod 'GooglePlaces'. Error **Use of unresolved identifier** usually occurs when your new class has a different Target(s) from the other one. You can check it in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996730/use-of-unresolved-identifier-in-swift). It might have a testing target and the other doesn't. You have to include all of your classes in the testing target or none of them. Also, here is a related [answer in SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38801323/5832311) which might help.

Comment: my error after migration to google places 2.0, old code dont work :( In 2.0 it dont see GMSPlacePickerConfig & GooglePlacePicker, In 1 version Google maps, all work good.