# No member 'data' error message (Swift, Xcode)

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I want to carry the variables CorrectAnswerTotal and QuestionsAskedTotal across to my second view controller (Score View Controller) however I keep getting the error message 'Type 'ScoreViewController' has no member 'data''

Could someone tell me how to resolve this please.

Another issue is I am unable to call on these variables separately in my original view controller since adding them into a structure. I am a beginner at programming so is there a certain way that this should be done?

Thanks in advance.

```
 struct CarryToNextViewController {

var CorrectAnswerTotal = 0
var QuestionsAskedTotal = 0


}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

let ViewController:ScoreViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ScoreViewController
ScoreViewController.data = CarryToNextViewController(CorrectAnswerTotal: Int, QuestionsAskedTotal: Int)

}
```

EDIT

Even when renaming `ScoreViewController` as `viewController` I still get the same error message. This is the edited code:

```
  class viewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var QuestionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Buttons: [UIButton]!

var Questions = [Question]()
var QuestionNumber = Int()
var AnswerNumber = Int()

struct CarryToNextViewController {

var CorrectAnswerTotal = 0
var QuestionsAskedTotal = 0


}

 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)       {

  let ViewController:ScoreViewController = segue.destinationViewController as!  ScoreViewController
  viewController.data = CarryToNextViewController(CorrectAnswerTotal: 0, QuestionsAskedTotal: 0)
```

}

Comment: To avoid those errors – you are supposed to refer to `ViewController` rather than `ScoreViewController` conform to the naming convention by naming variable names starting with a lowercase letter and class names starting with a capital letter.

Comment: You are assigning values using class type instead of reference on type. Try ViewController.data = CarryToNextViewController(CorrectAnswerTotal: 0, QuestionsAskedTotal: 0)

Answer (score 2):

`ScoreViewController` is a class, not a variable.  Try `ViewController.data = ...` instead, though you should rename it to `viewController` to reduce confusion.

(In fact, using standard variable/class naming throughout would make the code easier to analyze.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, however when I change `ScoreViewController` to `viewController` I get the error message 'Use of unresolved identifier 'viewController'.

Comment: Did you rename `ViewController` where you assigned a value to it?

Comment: I've done that and the code still doesn't seem to work, I've edited it within my question so it will hopefully be clear where I've gone wrong.

Comment: @SausageMachine he didn't rename the class, his first view controller is named `viewController`

Comment: you should check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996730/use-of-unresolved-identifier-in-swift

Comment: @EllaHiggins  Even in the edited version you have `ViewController` and `viewController`.  The compiler is case-sensitive, so it doesn't think those are the same things.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `viewController.data` to access `let ViewController:ScoreViewController` because they have different variable names(first one is UpperCase second one is LowerCase) they should be the same.

Since your first view controller is called `viewController` to avoid even more confusion I suggest you replace these two line:

```
let ViewController:ScoreViewController = segue.destinationViewController as!  ScoreViewController
viewController.data = CarryToNextViewController(CorrectAnswerTotal: 0, QuestionsAskedTotal: 0)
```

with

```
let destViewController:ScoreViewController = segue.destinationViewController as!  ScoreViewController
destViewController.data = CarryToNextViewController(CorrectAnswerTotal: 0, QuestionsAskedTotal: 0)
```