# Where do I declare a variable on app launch, that accesses ViewController properties?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I have a class of which I want to create an instance as soon as the app launches. I would like to initialize some of its properties from switches/toggles in my ViewController.

Here is the class, of which I am trying to create an instance:

```
import Foundation

class PropertyCollection {
    var property1: Bool

    init (property1: Bool) {
        self.property1 = property1

    }

    func disableAll() {
        self.property1 = false

    }

    func enableAll() {
        self.property1 = true

    }

    func info() -> String {
        return "The properties are: \(property1)"
    }

}
```

So: 
Putting the declaration in `AppDelegate.swift` gives me an **error** (**"Use of unresoved identifier 'property1Switch'"**):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        var thePropertyCollection: PropertyCollection = PropertyCollection(property1: property1Switch.isOn)

        return true
    }
```

Adding "ViewController." in front of "property1switch" doesn't help either. I get another **error** ("**Instance Member 'property1Switch' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'"**)

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    var thePropertyCollection: PropertyCollection = PropertyCollection(property1: ViewController.property1Switch.isOn)

    return true
}
```

**But I am not trying to "use type 'property1Switch' on type 'View Controller'". I thought this was how you reference stuff from other classes?**

Comment: Can you please share code of class PropertyCollection?  is PropertyCollection is a controller class?

Comment: Added the class. I do not know what a controller class is, but my guess is no.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

See you are initializing this object, so you must provide it initial value.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        var thePropertyCollection: PropertyCollection = PropertyCollection(property1: true)

        return true
}
```

Comment: That is not what I am trying to do. I do wish to provide an initial value, but it should come from `property1Switch` which is a property of `ViewController`.
That is where the problem arises.

Answer (score 0):

You may be in dealing with a similar issue as this one:
['Use of Unresolved Identifier' in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996730/use-of-unresolved-identifier-in-swift)
One possible issue is that your new class has a different Target(s) from the other one.

For example, it might have a testing target and the other doesn't. For this specific case, you have to include all of your classes in the testing target or none of them.