# Use of unresolved identifier swift 3

Tags: swift

So I have an old app that needs to be updated and this was the original code that worked:

```
myBtn.addTarget(nil, action:("addNewObject"), for:.touchUpInside)
```

"addNewObject" is a function common in several different classes of which an instance of myBtn will exist. However after trying to update the code to Swift 3
as below, I now get the "Use of unresolved identifier" error.

```
myBtn.addTarget(nil, action:(#selector(addNewObject)), for:.touchUpInside)
```

Comment: I think your target needs to be self not nil.

Comment: change `nil` to `self`

Comment: After I change to self I still get "Use of unresolved identifier" error.

Comment: Try following solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996730/use-of-unresolved-identifier-in-swift

Comment: myBtn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(anyClass.addNewObject), for:.touchUpInside) I think the issue might be that I need a generic thing like "anyClass" so any class can call addNewObject as long as that class has addNewObject(). So what syntax can I use in place of anyClass here?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use **nil**, use **self**

```
myBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addNewObject), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Implement *addNewObject* method like this,

```
@IBAction func addNewObject() {
    //Your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The target can not be nil. Change "nil" to "self".

```
myBtn.addTarget(self, action: (#selector(addNewObject)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: After I change to self I still get "Use of unresolved identifier" error.

Comment: Then there must be some kind of typo in your code. (may be the name of the method or name of the variable or something)  Please check for that also.